# How to pass App argument to os.system()

Tags: python, macos

I am able to start application using quite simple syntax. Example

```
app="/Applications/MyApp/myAppExecutable"
file="/Users/userName/Pictures/myPicture.jpg"

cmd="open -a '%s' '%s'" % (app, file)

os.system(cmd)
```

Resulted `cmd` here is:

```
open -a '/Applications/MyApp/myAppExecutable' '/Users/userName/Pictures/myPicture.jpg'
```

and it runs just fine.

But the application I am running accepts an optional startup argument `-proj filepath`, so a full `cmd` string with this optional argument should look like:

```
open -a '/Applications/MyApp/myAppExecutable' -proj '/Users/userName/Pictures' '/Users/userName/Pictures/myPicture.jpg'
```

But if I feed `os.system()` with a such cmdstring I am getting:

```
open: invalid option -- p
```

How to pass an optional app argument without causing an error and crash?

Comment: Does that syntax work from the command line? Looks more like an `open` problem then a Python problem.

Comment: If you run that at the command line, does it work?

Comment: This is an `open` problem, not a Python problem. Try passing `--` between the application path and its argument. If all else fails, you can also simply launch it without `open`, you only have to execute `/Applications/MyApp/myAppExecutable/Contents/MacOS/myAppExecutable` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite possible to submit the application's specific arguments to OS `open` command.
The syntax to `open`:

```
open -a /path/to/application/executable.file /filepath/to/the/file/to/open/with/app.ext
```

It appears it is OK to enclose both paths in double or single quotes such as:

```
open -a '/path/to/application/executable.file' '/filepath/to/the/file/to/open/with/app.ext'
```

As **Ned** has mentioned flag `--args` can be used to specify any Application's specific startup flags.
The App specific flags are placed after `open`'s `--args` flag such as:

```
open -a /path/to/application/executable.file  --args -proj
```

The problem is that the App specific flags (such as `-proj`) will only be passed at the time the App is starting up. If it is already running the `open -a` command will only open a file (if the file_to_be_opened is specified)  but won't deliver the App's specific args. By other words the App is only able to receive its args at the time it starts.
There is `-n` flag available to be used with `open -a` command. When used `open -a` will start as many instances of Apps as needed. Each of App instances will get the App args properly.

```
open -a '/path/to/application/executable.file' '/filepath/to/the/file/to/open/with/app.ext -n --args -proj "SpecificToApp arg or command" '
```

It all translates if used with `subprocess`:

```
subprocess.check_call(['open', '-a', app, file, '-n', '--args', '-proj', 'proj_flag_values'])
```

or simply pass it as a string arg to:

```
os.system(cmdString)
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the `open` man page, you have to pass `--args` before arguments to the program:

```
 --args
     All remaining arguments are passed to the opened application in the
     argv parameter to main().  These arguments are not opened or inter-
     preted by the open tool.
```

As an aside, you may want to look into using `subprocess`. Here's how the command looks like with `subprocess`:

```
subprocess.check_call(['open', '-a', app, file])
```

No fiddling with string interpolation required.

Comment: You still need `--args` and `-proj` when using `subprocess`.

Comment: @nneonneo: Where do we put `--args` flag: at the beginning, middle or the end of line? Do you really know a solution? I can do copy/paste from docs - it is not that difficult. Post an example if you really know the answer.

Comment: @Sputnix: why don't you try it in various positions and report back? I googled the man page.