# How to pass variable in os.system

Tags: python, windows, windows-task-scheduler

I am making a python program which will assign a task to the task scheduler (on Windows) to run a command once at a specific time.

I have a command, say, `command1 = "C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe"` and I have a task name say, `cmd_name = "calculator"`
Now, I am passing these two variables in
`os.system(r'SchTasks /Create /SC ONCE /TN '+cmd_name+' /TR '+cmd+' /ST 17:28')`

But, the task does not get scheduled.

I have referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66597073/how-to-pass-python-variable-in-os-system-or-subprocess), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34185488/variable-in-os-system), and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195723/how-to-pass-app-argument-to-os-system), but all of these do not help me as I am not passing a string as a whole in os.system(), instead there is an extra *r* in my command.

How do I pass these variables? I can also try any other method (using python) if someone suggest to schedule the task at a specific time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using `subprocess`

```
import os
import subprocess
command1 = "C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe"
cmd_name = "calculator"
cmd = 'SchTasks /Create /SC ONCE /TN "'+cmd_name+'" /TR "'+command1+'" /ST 18:24'
subprocess.run(cmd)
```